# Can't inflate Fragment dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout-inflater, android-inflate

I am following [this](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/) tutorial to inflate fragments in default Navigation drawer activity in Android Studio.
After compiling I get the following error in logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mayurn.sidepanel2/com.example.mayurn.sidepanel2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

public static String TAG = "mytag";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);         //set Action bar
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);       //Fab snackbar
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);          //Drawer parameters
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();                                            //show present view in drawer

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    displaySelectedFrame(R.id.nav_camera);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {                                 //inflate the setting menu
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    displaySelectedFrame(item.getItemId());

    return true;

}

public void displaySelectedFrame(int itemId){

    Fragment f = null;

    switch(itemId){

        case R.id.nav_camera:
            f = new frag_1();
            break;

        case R.id.nav_gallery:
            f = new frag_2();
            break;

        case R.id.nav_manage:
            f = new frag_3();
            break;
    }

    if(f!=null){

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_fragment , f);
        ft.commit();

    }

DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
```

}

Now the important part-->>

My layout relation is like this `activity_main->(include)->app_bar_main->(include)->content_main->(contain)fragment`

Here are files:

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.mayurn.sidepanel2.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.mayurn.sidepanel2.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content_fragment"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now  I think this fragment tag is why I can't inflate fragment.
The preview layout is also giving a rendering error because I didn't set the `android:name` parameter.

But I want to load it after the user clicks an item from navigation panel so it's of no use.

If I add this line `android:name="com.example.mayurn.sidepanel2.frag_1"` the app runs but I get fragment overlapping issues like frag_1 sits prominently and other fragment overlaps it.

I want to load the fragment dynamically without setting the `android:name` parameter.

Thank you any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Change `<fragment>` to `<FrameLayout>`. Since you're loading the `Fragment`s dynamically, you just need an empty `ViewGroup` to hold their `View`s. The `<fragment>` tag is for static `Fragment`s.

Comment: @MikeM. put it on answer.

Comment: It's cool. You can accept the posted answer, if you like. I was looking for a duplicate, but I can't seem to find a decent one, at the moment.

Comment: @mayurnewase You should read the tutorial again. `<FrameLayout>` is clearly used in that layout

Comment: Yup my bad i thought i know this one and did blindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead of fragment tag.

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: thank you but it was solved by @mikeM.should i wait for him to answer or accept this one.i am confused